# Printing barcodes using java library withing PHP

Tags: java, php, apache, wamp

I have a `html` button linked to `php` page. The `php` page calls a `jar` file which has to print barcodes on the barcode printer on the server (the default and the only network printer  installed). 
I'm calling it as within my `php`.

```
$out = system("java -jar C:\\wamp\\bprint\\bprint.jar ABC1234");
```

The `jar` works fine in the command line (and prints the barcodes) but it doesn't print anything within my php page. I know the `jar` is being called in my `php` page because a `System.Out.Println();` within my jar executes fine. Other executable are working too within system()

I am running `WAMP` on `Windows XP` and `Apache` is running as a `Admin` user.

My question is, it the printing part being blocked by `PHP` or `Java` or `Apache`. How should I overcome it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you testing that "The jar works fine in the command line" as the same user that your apache server is running as?  If not, sounds like a permissions issue to me.  EDIT: You edited in WAMP and that you're running as Admin.  Does Admin have that printer installed and set as default?

Comment: yes.. its the same Admin user..

Comment: So the issue is that `$out` isn't being populated with the console output of the java command?

Comment: @jli may be.. BTW I also tried shell_exec() and passthru()

Comment: @jedwards yes.. I'm running both apache and command prompt as admin. Thats the only printer installed and set as default under admin..

Comment: Consider wrapping your java command in a batch file, and prepending the java command with the [commands to (possibly add and) select a default printer](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/9e52c5e2-cd0f-413b-acad-a010b031d44d/)

Comment: @jedwards Thanks.. that sounds promising.. Let me try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`system`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) only returns the **last line** of stdout. Try using [`exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) with the `array &$output` parameter.

```
$out = array();
exec("java -jar C:\\wamp\\bprint\\bprint.jar ABC1234", $out);
var_dump($out);
```

Comment: It didn't work. It printed array (size=1)
  0 => string 'Please wait while program generate barcodes.......' (length=50)

Comment: That text is from my java program

Comment: @Ankur So you are getting output.. What's missing? Maybe it's getting printed to stderr?

Comment: yes, Thats what i'm gettin as output.. but nothing is printing. it prints in the command line if i give the exact same command.. the path is right..